# How do you install the plastic/nylon toggle anchors?

Tags: installation, drywall-anchor

I recently bought a shelf that included these types of wall anchors, and for the life of me, I could not figure out how to install them. What's the trick with them?

[image: ss#1]

They are also shown on the Lowes website here too: [TOGGLER 20-Pack Plastic Toggle 5/8-in to 3/4-in Drywall Anchors with #8 x 1-3/4-in Screws](http://www.lowes.com/pd_133193-10337-50550_4294710796__?productId=3183871#BVRRWidgetID)

Comment: These, when gauged for the proper thickness of wall are the best hollow wall anchors for many things I do. They can be used in concrete, the plastic is soft enough even if you miss getting it in the exact spot you need in concrete, you can push the screw directly into the plastic, not needing the predrilled hole, although when you do drill it right, it is nice too. Soooo much better than many other plastic hollow wall anchors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this video on youtube titled: "[Plastic Toggle Anchors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PV3Sb77VLy4)" that shows their installation. The trick is to use your index finger to push in the toggle so that it can collapse down into a "barrel" shape for insertion into a pre-drilt hole in the dry-wall.

Here are the key shots from that video.

*image #1*

[image: ss#1]

*image #2*

[image: ss#2]

*image #3*

[image: ss#3]

*image #4*

[image: ss#4]

Answer (score 1):

The [manufacturers web site](http://www.toggler.com/) offers [installation instructions](http://www.toggler.com/products/plastic-toggle/installation.php), as well as a helpful video. An [instructional video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEOk1RxHtkc&list=UUW9d9SyomTVG_7XiAqzRZ5A) can also be found on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/).

> [image: Installation instructions]